# How can I make evernote web clipper sync to my desktop app faster or instantly?

Tags: synchronization, evernote, mac, google-chrome-extensions

I use the Evernote web clipper in Chrome quite a bit, and sometimes I want to immediately open the item in the Evernote desktop app on my Mac.  However, the fastest sync setting is "every 5 minutes".

I dug around in the preferences/plist file on my Mac and couldn't even find any key/value pairs that appeared to store your sync settings.  I also opened up the sqlite db and found nothing seemingly related.

Anyone know of a way I can shorten this, or even use a push sync model?

<sub>P.S.  wasn't sure if the apple site would be better for this, but I guess we'll see what the community thinks and I'll maybe redo this over after a day or two.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Evernote doesn't support pushing content into the client.  Having the client continuously polling their servers at a very frequent interval would place a lot of unnecessary load on their servers, which is probably why the minimum is 5 minutes.

The best solution is to manually press the 'Sync' button in the client if you want to immediately view a note that you just clipped from Chrome.  It only adds a few seconds for something you want to view immediately, and if you don't end up viewing it instantly, it will show up 5 minutes (or less) later when the automatic sync happens.